# undefined is not a function: Backbone + Require router issue

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, backbone-routing

Not sure what is wrong here. I am either missing a require, logic in my "index" route, or part of my structure is incomplete.  Does anyone see what is wrong here?

**router.js**

```
    define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'views/drafts'
], function($, _, Backbone, DraftsList) {

  var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      "": "index"
    },

    index: function() {
      var draftsList = new DraftsList();
      draftsList.render();
    }
  });

  return Router;

});
```

**views/drafts.js**

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'collections/drafts'
  ], function($, _, Backbone, draftsCollection){

        var draftsList = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: '.content',
            var drafts = new draftsCollection();
            drafts.fetch({
                var template = _.template($('#drafts-template').html(), {drafts: drafts.models});
                this.$el.html(template);
            })
        });

}
```

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/template" id="drafts-template">
  <h4>This should display</h4>
</script>
```

main.js (in case somehow it helps)

```
require([
    'app', 
    'router'
], function(app, Router) {

  app.router = new Router();
  Backbone.history.start();

});
```

error in the console is "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (router.js line 14)"

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your drafts.js module doesn't return anything so `DraftsList` inside router.js is `undefined`. Advice from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18078607/1240557) applies here too.

Comment: Ah yes, that would do it. Thanks for the tip.